# Will elements of a Cassandra's collection column locate in different sstable?

Tags: cassandra

I have a table saying  create table{user text, page text, visit_time list, primary key(user, page)}. if a user visited the same page again 50 min after the first visit. in this case, will the two visit times locate in two sstables? Will compaction make them in one place later on?

Answer (score 0):

Data is initially stored in memory in memtables and are pushed into an SSTable when a 'flush' is executed.

A flush occurs:

- When the memtable becomes full
- When nodetool flush is manually executed

So it depends on your memtable size (as set in the cassandra.yaml) and your write load as to how long it takes for the memtable to become full and for a flush to disk to occur. For most workloads, a flush will probably occur in a 50 minute window.

The compaction process will indeed combine multiple SSTables into one so that all your records will be located in the same SSTable.